# Chaining Multiple Mutating Webhooks in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

I’ve got two mutating web hook configurations deployed to the cluster, each configuration has got one webhook pointing to its corresponding web hook server,

#### Mutating-config-1

```
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    apiVersions: ["v1"]
    operations: ["CREATE"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    scope: "*"
clientConfig:
  service:
    namespace: test
    name: webhook-server-1
    path: /mutate
    port: 443
```

#### Mutating-config-2

```
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    apiVersions: ["v1"]
    operations: ["CREATE"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    scope: "*"
clientConfig:
  service:
    namespace: test
    name: webhook-server-2
    path: /mutate
    port: 443
```

when I deployed and tested, I can see that it working as follows,

> API Server --> Mutating Webhook 1 --> Validating Webhooks --> ..

> API Server --> Mutating Webhook 2 --> Validating Webhooks --> ..

Now, my question is, is it possible to chain the mutating webhook calls before it hits the Validating Webhooks? e.g.

> API Server --> Mutating Webhook 1 --> Mutating Webhook 2 --> Validating Webhooks --> ..

or to run them in specific order? e.g.

> API Server --> Mutating Webhook 2 --> Validating webhooks --> ..

> API Server --> Mutating Webhook 1 --> Validating Webhooks --> ..

Any suggestions/ideas are greatly appreciated.